# Returning values from Swing using invokeAndWait

Tags: java, swing, event-dispatch-thread, invokeandwait

I've been using the following approach to create components and return values from Swing to/from outside the EDT. For instance, the following method could be an extension to `JFrame`, to create a `JPanel` and add it to the parent `JFrame`:

```
public JPanel threadSafeAddPanel() {

    final JPanel[] jPanel = new JPanel[1];

    try {
        EventQueue.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                jPanel[0] = new JPanel();
                add(jPanel[0]);
            }
        });
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
    } catch (InvocationTargetException ex) {
    }

    return jPanel[0];
}
```

The local 1-length array is used to transfer the "result" from inside the `Runnable`, which is invoked in the EDT. Well, it looks "a bit" hacky, and so my questions:

1. Does this make sense? Is anybody else doing something like this?
2. Is the 1-length array a good way of transferring the result?
3. Is there an easier way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Swallowing exceptions without even logging them: *bad!!* - you will hate yourself when you come upon something like that after a 2 hours bug-hunt
- No, the array is not a good way; for one thing, it offers no easy method for the calling code to wait for the EDT thread to execute the `Runnable` before fetching the result
- There's a class designed explicitly for this kind of thing: [`SwingWorker`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html)

Comment: 1. You're right :-) 2. Ok, but invokeAndWait does that. 3. Perhaps I should be using it, although for simple "getters" it feels a bit overkill.

Comment: 1. SwingWorker isn't a hammer you can use to fix all threading issues in Swing applications. 2. SwingWorker is for running things on background threads but this question is about creating a panel, which must be run on the EDT anyway - the exact opposite of what SwingWorker helps you do.

Answer (score 3):

Although that method may make sense in some situations, it will be useless most of the time.

The reason is that the creation of most (if not all) of your components will always occur from the EDT, as a result of a user action (menu item or button clicked) which are always executed from the EDT.

In cases where you have big work to perform before creating your panel and you don't want to block the EDT, then you should, as suggested by someone else, use SwingWorker or a Swing framework that offer support for long tasks (generally based on SwingWorker internally anyway, but not necessarily).

Regarding your question 2, unfortunately you don't have many ways to do that:

- Use a 1-item array as you did, that's
  the easiest but also ugliest solution
- Create a ItemHolder class (see
  below) that does almost the same,
  requires a bit more work and is
  cleaner, in my opinion
- Last, use java.util.concurrent
  facilities (Future and Callable);
  that would be the cleaniest I think,
  but also it requires the most effort

Here is, simplified, the ItemHolder class:

```
public class ItemHolder<T> {
    public void set(T item) {...}
    public T get() {...}
    private T item;
}
```

Comment: +1 to the suggestion in here about ignoring the threading issue because the odds are this method will be called from the EDT anyway. I would just assert isEventDispatchThread() and remove all the boilerplate - delay the issue until someone actually calls it from another thread, because YAGNI.

Answer (score 0):

1. a) It makes sense. b)not that I know of.
2. As good as any.
3. Create the JPanel outside of the `invokeAndWait` call

//This line added to appease markdown

```
public JPanel threadSafeAddPanel() {
    final JPanel jPanel = new JPanel();
    try {
        EventQueue.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                add(jPanel);
            }
        });
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
    } catch (InvocationTargetException ex) {
    }
    return jPanel;
}
```

Comment: While 3. most likely works, it's not strictly speaking allowed.

Comment: I agree with Joonas, creating Swing components outside the EDT creates a bad precedent and should be avoided.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily check to see if the current thread is the EDT and then execute correctly and more simply in that context. As for using the final array for getting the return value, that is the easiest way when you have to use an anonymous inner class like this.

```
public JPanel threadSafeAddPanel() throws InterruptedException, 
        InvocationTargetException {
    if (EventQueue.isDispatchThread()) {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        add(panel);

        return panel; 
    } else {
        final JPanel[] jPanel = new JPanel[1];
        EventQueue.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                jPanel[0] = new JPanel();
                add(jPanel[0]);
            }
        });

        return jPanel[0];
    }
}
```